# textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange is executing one step behind user action

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a `textField` into which the user types an email address. I want to activate the submit button at the instant the input text becomes a valid email address.

The validation works, but the code in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` appears to execute one step behind the user input. So when the email is valid, the user still has to tap one more key before the button changes. And likewise, if the email address becomes invalid, the button doesn't change until one more key is tapped.

Note that this happens on the device too, not just in the simulator.

Code is below:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) {
    if emailIsValidFormat(textField.text) {
        emailSubmitButton.alpha = 1
    } else {
        emailSubmitButton.alpha = 0.4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text hasn't changed yet when this method is called. You have to use`range` and `replacementString` to construct the email address, and then verify that.

Comment: This worked! I looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621496/how-shouldchangecharactersinrange-works-in-swift) for some guidance on how to use `replacementString`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`, it would probably be simpler to connect the “Editing Changed” event of your text field to an action in your view controller. The text field sends `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` **before** it updates its `text` property, but it sends the “Editing Changed” event **after** it updates its `text` property.

Example:

[image: connect Editing Changed event]

Comment: Are you really using a proportional font for code? :)

Answer (score 1):

move your code to another place, let call it:
`func validateEmail(emailTextField: UITextField) -> Bool`
here the important part:

`yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: "validateEmail:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)` or `.ValueChanged`

`validateEmail:` will be called everytime your string changed.

Comment: By the way, this works too, using `UIControlEvents.EditingChanged`.