# Textfield shouldChangeCharactersIn for password field clear

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4, uitextfielddelegate

I am using MVVM Structure and when textfield value changed update the view model.
Everything working fine except password field

Here is code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text,
        let range = Range.init(range, in: text) {

        let newText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if textField == txtOldPassword {
            changePasswordViewModel.updateOldPassword(string: newText)
        } else if textField == txtNewPassword {
            changePasswordViewModel.updateNewPassword(string: newText)
        } else if textField == txtConfirmPassword {
            changePasswordViewModel.updateConfirmPassword(string: newText)
        }  
    }

    return true
}
```

as password filed cleared when backspace (or delete button) tapped from keyboard `newText` is returning previously set value not empty string.

**issue: when password field is clear still `newText` has string**

When I try to see range returned by function it not looks valid

> po range
>   expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=10, address=0x107a2b000).
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

[image]

I know I can do it `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = false;` but I want it to be clear as default functionality.

Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: As you said, `newText ` returns previously set value is because you are checking with `textField.text` instead of `string ` parameter. `textField.text` will return available value in text field and `string ` will return the value that is going to be added. This delegate method excutes before any changes occures in textfield

Comment: @Priya Thanks for your response. As you know range will return area of string which is modified by user in textfield if you observe `text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)` I am replacing string in my current text with range. It is working in every case except Password field

Comment: @Priya As When you refocus on textfield and press back or delete button whole text would be cleared so in that case it is not working !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is called before text on textField is changed so it's not right place to do these works.

We have another way to check text changed and I think it can resolve your problem.

```
txtOldPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
txtNewPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
txtConfirmPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) -> Void {
  if let text = textField.text {
    if textField == txtOldPassword {
      changePasswordViewModel.updateOldPassword(string: text)
    } else if textField == txtNewPassword {
      changePasswordViewModel.updateNewPassword(string: text)
    } else if textField == txtConfirmPassword {
      changePasswordViewModel.updateConfirmPassword(string: text)
    }
  }
}
```

`textFieldDidChange(textField:)` will be called after text is changed.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just copied your code. Thank for correcting my answer.

Comment: Working fine !! Thanks for your efforts accepted and upvoted

Comment: Welcome my friend !