# How to change font in textview dynamically with button tap in swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitextview, uppercase

I created a textview like below and I add keyboard button for users can change the font. It is working but it changes whole text's font but I want to change fonts only after button clicking. Can you help about ?

```
   func setKeyboard() { // this is for keyboard button

    let bar = UIToolbar()

    let flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

     let font = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-image-80"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(fontTapped))

bar.barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30/255, green: 30/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1)
bar.sizeToFit()

    writePost.inputAccessoryView = bar

}

// and this one is fontTapped function

   @objc func fontTapped() {

    if fontTag == 0 {
       let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: writePost.text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)])
         writePost.attributedText = attributedText
        fontTag = 1

    } else {

        writePost.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 16)
        fontTag = 0
}
}
```

Comment: Unclear what "I want to change fonts only after button clicking" means. You are saying `writePost.attributedText = attributedText` which changes the font of the whole text view; it is unclear what else you expect or what else you want. Can you explain more clearly? Maybe give an example of what you're hoping to do?

Comment: okey for example I am writing; "hello world " with  Italic font this is default font for my textview. Then I clicked "fontTapped" and writing: "I am x code". So I want to "hello world" still Italic font but "I am x Code " change to bold characters

Answer (score 1):

To change the font / style for what the user types *from now on*, change the `typingAttributes` of the text view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes

Answer (score 0):

You will be using the attributedText property of the UITextField like so:

https://medium.com/swift-india/multiple-font-style-for-uilable-text-using-nsattributed-string-3f121036a533

And probably build your attributed string in shouldChangeCharactersInRange() of the UITextFieldDelegate, in order to change the font of the incoming characters.

[How shouldChangeCharactersInRange works in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621496/how-shouldchangecharactersinrange-works-in-swift)