# Swift prevent "0" being first character for 1 specific uiTextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

so i search online about how "func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool" for formating textField. i found this way to prevent "0" as my first char in my textfield. it works but, actually not the way i wanted.

The thing is, in my register view theres 4 uiTextfield, which contain :

- Name
- Phone Number
- Pin
- Confirm Pin

i only want to prevent "0" as my first char only for my PhoneNum TextField. but with this code, i kinda put all of those 4 textField into prevent "0" as the first char.

here's my code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFullName: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textPhoneNumber: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textPIN: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textConfirmPIN: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    // I try this one
    if string == "0" {
        if textField.text!.count == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    // i also try to change the "textField" into "textPhoneNumber"
    if string == "0" {
        if textPhoneNumber.text!.count == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    

   // both of those method wont work
  
    return true
}
```

can someone tell me how to just prevent my textPhoneNumber to cannot type "0" as its first char? with this method i only put all of my textfield into cannot type "0" as its first char.

Thanks guys

Comment: `if textField == textPhoneNumber { do the stuff check } else { return true }`  Can be written with a `guard else` too: `guard textField == textPhoneNumber else { return true } do the stuff check`

Comment: Also, before doing your test, you should discover what the resulting string will be.  See answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621496/how-shouldchangecharactersinrange-works-in-swift .  That approach handles the case where the user types "90", then goes back and deletes the "9".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UITextFieldDelegate methods will get called for ALL of the text fields for which the view controller is set up as the delegate.

Presumably your `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` method is being called for all 4 of your `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` objects (which I assume are a custom subclass of UITextField.)

If you want different behavior for different text fields, you need to write your code to handle each case separately. Something like this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    switch textField {
        case textPhoneNumber:
            //Special case code to handle the phone number field
            if string == "0" {
                if textField.text!.count == 0 {
                   return false
                }
                return true
            }

        case textFullName:
            //Special case code to handle the name field (if needed.)
        default:
            //Shared code to handle the other fields the same way
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `textField` is `textPhoneNumber` directly by using the equatability `==` sign.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == textPhoneNumber {
        // do textPhoneNumber stuff
    } else {
        // others
    }
    return true
}
```